# Second-order total differential of f(x): dx as a constant

Tags: calculus

I am reading "Mathematics for Economics" by Michael Hoy et al. and getting stuck in this basic question about Second-order total differential of one-variable function f(x).
The authors state that "we often regard dx as a given constant" and treat it just like that. Please clarify this for me. My simple thought is that dx acts as an estimate for delta(x), we, therefore, can think of it as a constant. Please refer to the picture for more detail. 
Thank you for your time!

[image: Mathematics for Economics]

Comment: I've edited the tags: ["second-order logic" is a topic in mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic), unrelated to the topic of this question.

Comment: I am not sure this (part of the book) is proper math.

Comment: @Fabian  This looks to me as if the author is trying to simplify (to a workable extreme) the fact that, if $d$ is the exterior derivative (or rather, the total derivative, which, under a non-formal point of view they "coincide" for functions), then $d \circ d = 0$. By $dx^2$ he really means $dx \wedge dx$.